# TestComplete ; Automation Testing; Dynamic programming

Tags: automated-testing, data-driven

How do we take input from an excel sheet(data-driven testing) for web app testing after recording a script? making it dynamic is the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Aakash! 
TestComplete offers you two possible ways that can be used to create data-driven tests:

- DB Table variables (Database tables or queries, Excel files, CSV files)
- Table variables
- DDT program object

**How to perform data-driven testing:**

1. Create a TestComplete project
2. Record an automated test
3. Modify the Data-Driven Test and Assign Input Values
4. Change the Operation’s Execution Order
5. Executing a Data-Driven Test and Checking Results

***So, on step 3 you may use excel file.*** 
More details you may find here:

- http://support.smartbear.com/articles/testcomplete/data-driven-testing (Modifying the Data-Driven Test and Assigning Input Values)